# Postgres: After converting from bytea to varchar '\r' remains

Tags: windows, postgresql, utf-8, varchar, bytea

I have a table which contains xml file as binary data. The xmls contains "\r\n" characters as "\015\012" in bytea. I need to change the column type from bytea to varchar.

I run:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN xml_data TYPE VARCHAR;
UPDATE my_table SET xml_data = convert_from(xml_data::bytea, 'UTF8');
```

And it works for linux. But on Windows it converts '\015' to "\r" (two characters). So I have something like that in the result:

```
<field>...</field>\r
<field>...</field>
```

Maybe there is an proper method to convert binary data to UTF?

Comment: No conversion will strip actual data from your input. `\r` is perfectly valid in UTF-8 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to strip the carriage returns in a separate step.

If you are ok with getting rid of them wholesale, I suggest something like:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
   ALTER xml_data TYPE text
      USING replace(
               convert_from(xml_data, 'UTF8'),
               E'\r',
               ''
            );
```

Is there a good reason for using data type `varchar` (or `text`, which is the same) rather than `xml`?

Comment: Thanks! That's it. There is no reason to use varchar instead of xml, just have to work with this code.